# How to expand $(1+ \frac{1}{x})^n$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I recently saw the expansion $(1+ \frac{1}{x})^n = 1 +   \frac{n}{x}  + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!x^2} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{3!x^3}.... $ where  $n \in \mathbb Q$

From what I understood, they have taken the Taylor series of $(1+x)^n$ and put $x=\frac{1}{t}$. This doesn't make sense to me because the Taylor series used, uses successive derivatives at zero but derivatives at zero won't be defined for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

How can I directly calculate the Taylor series for  $(1+ \frac{1}{x})^n$?

Comment: Well, the above expression is not a Taylor series. But that does mean it is wrong. There is no Taylor series at $x=0$ because $(1+1/x)^n$ has a pole at $x=0.$ So when you ask for a Taylor series, we usually ask, "around what $x?$" Here, you could use any center $x\neq 0.$

Comment: This is just a binomial expansion with $n$ an integer

Comment: So the two sides of the expansion are equal, but the right side is not a Taylor series. Did the place you saw it call it a Taylor series? In some places, they'll write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{-n}$ the Taylor series around $\infty.$  Or they'll call it a Laurent series.

Comment: If you want in terms of series. It should be a Laurent series around $+\infty$. Of course, it is easier to use the expansion in terms of Newton's generalized binomial.

Comment: @MarkBennet the specific expansion I saw has a fractional exponent ($n= \frac{1}{3}$). That's why I didn't consider Binomial theorem

Comment: As written, then, for general real $n,$ the equation is a Laurent series for $(1+1/x)^n$ which converges for $|x|>1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry! I didn't know how to write $\in$ in MathJax so I left that out, out of laziness. I have added it in the edit. I'll read up on Laurent series. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equation is not a Taylor series, but it is correct, at least for $x \geq 1$.

The usual Taylor series

$$ (1+t)^n = 1 + nt + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} t^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} t^3 + \cdots $$

is a true equation for every rational $n$ and every real $t$ with $-1 < t \leq 1$, in the sense that the infinite series converges to $(1+t)^n$. (Also for some other domains, but in general we may need to worry about when $a^b$ even has a clear meaning.) This fact is related to repeated derivatives, but we don't need those derivatives to just say that the equation holds true.

If $x \geq 1$, then $0 < \frac{1}{x} \leq 1$. So just by substitution, it is true that

$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n = 1 + \frac{n}{x} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!\, x^2} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!\, x^3} + \cdots $$

Comment: You can have issues if $t=-1$ and $n$ is negative. I do not see why you allow $n$ to be rational but not a general real or complex number. As long as $-1<t<1$, there is now issue with that.

Comment: @Gary Fixed $t = -1$. I agree $n$ can be irrational, but the OP has $n \in \mathbb{Q}$. If there could be an issue about what an irrational power means, I figured I'd just avoid it.

Comment: I understand. You did not fix it though.

Comment: @Gary Forgot to click Save, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Expand $(x+1)^n$ as a Taylor series. Then divide through by $x^n$.

Comment: More subtlety is needed for the infinite series for $n$ which is rational but not an integer.